# Turbolinks Doesn't Replace Title Tag In Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

My Rails application uses [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

Turbolinks is definitely active, but when I navigate between pages the title tag is not replaced. If I turn off JavaScript, each page displays its unique page title correctly.

My title tag is the first item in my page head:

```
<head>
  <%= page_title_tag %>
  ...
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'public/public', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  ...
</head>
```

The only documentation I can find regarding the title tag is this from the Turbbolinks README:

> Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and **the title in the head**.

**Update:** This appears to be Chrome-specific. Works fine in Firefox and Safari. Digging into the turbolinks JavaScript I can see that Turbolinks is definitely setting `document.title` with the correct value, however the title tag is not updating. I have also ripped out every piece of JavaScript in my application other than JQuery and Turbolinks, so this appears not to be app-specific. I'd be interested if anyone with a Turbolinks-enabled app in production could take a look in Chrome (OSX) and see if the `<title>` tag changes.

Versions:

```
Turbolinks 2.5.2
Rails 4.1.5
```

Comment: Try adding `data-no-transition-cache` to one of the DOM elements to disable page (and title) caching. Perhaps this will give you a hint. Rails specifically extracts the text content of the Title tag and the Body tag and replaces them on page load. So assuming `page_title_tag` returns some text, there should be no problem.

Comment: @nimrodm With `data-no-transition-cache` added to the page footer, there is no difference. The title tag is set to the title of the first visited page, then doesn't change again. `page_title_tag` definitely returns appropriate text. I can see this because I get correct page titles when JS is disabled and because the title of the first page I visit with JS/Turbolinks enabled is the correct title for that page. No two pages have the same title.

Comment: Well, if you want to really explore this thing: `bundle open turbolinks`, edit the file `lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee` and try placing `console.log title` at the beginning of `changePage` function and perhaps in `extractTitleAndBody` function -- right after the `title = ` line.  Turbolinks definitely update the title in my rails app...

Comment: Have you tried returning the title tags to your layout, and letting the helper handle only the title string itself? (It's a long shot, but I was wondering if that was confusing Rails during the rendering process, possibly relating to @nimrodm's comment.)

Comment: Please see my update. It's a Chrome-specific issue.

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce with my test app. I was using FFX but switched over to Chrome and can see XHRs being generated, along with my title changing. (I have a simple helper that generates a `content_tag` for title and outputs a string + random number.) Would it be worth creating and testing a simple, separate test app with scaffolding for comparison purposes?

Comment: @TK-421 Thanks for taking a look. I can see the XHRs being generated and I can see that Turbolinks is correctly setting `document.title` from its JS. In FF and Safari the tags are correctly replaced and running `document.title` from the console gives me the correct title. In Chrome however, this is not the case. In short, the means of generating the title is not the problem.

Comment: Have you already tried reproducing the issue with a freshly-generated test project? (nag)

Comment: Works flawlessly for me, too (and using both Chrome and Firefox). Just another data point.

Comment: @TK-421 You are right to nag. Stripped it back to nothing and still had a problem. Got me thinking if it wasn't Turbolinks and wasn't Chrome it had to be something in between … Disabled my extensions and the problem went away. Added my extensions back in one by one and found the culprit - an extensions called 'Lock Tab' which was overwriting the title the moment TL wrote it. Lesson learned.

Comment: @nimrodm Thanks for confirming that. Was really helpful.

Comment: @Pedr, you're welcome. Had a similar problem where Adblock was blocking a facebook icon on my site :)